# Get hostnames into ssh tab-completion (with minimal editing)

Tags: ssh, bash, command-line-interface

I know I could get a list of hostnames into bash tab-completion of `ssh` by adding them to `/etc/hosts`, but since they are on DHCP, it's kinda bad practice.

Does anyone know another DHCP-aware way, that doesn't force me to interfere with Ubuntu too much?

(Global solution preferred)

Comment: what OS is running your DHCP server?  What DHCP server is being used? Do you puppet or any configuration management system?  See - http://serverfault.com/questions/416779/smoothest-workflow-to-handle-ssh-host-verification-errors/416782#416782

Comment: I just have clients. DHCP is managed by hoster. Puppet is too much overhead for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with a good one myself:

`sudo sh -c "echo 'Host client1.hoster.org' >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config"`

works immediately and for every user :-)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to simply disable the `HashKnownHosts` option globally or in your personal `.ssh/config` file.  If you disable that, and also have the `bash-completion` package installed, then any host you connect to will be available for auto-completion after you have connected the first time.

You could use [ssh-keyscan](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keyscan) to build up a nice big list to pre-populate your known_hosts file.

Comment: My `known_hosts` file is `/dev/null` as Keys change frequently :-(

Comment: For auto-completion to be possible there has to be some source of data on your system that bash can use as a source. If you aren't defining your hosts anywhere on the local system you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Sure, but host id checking is just too damn naggy. Apart from that, I'd have to copy that file into every other users directory, overriding their's :-(