# What are storeconfigs in Puppet and what is their purpose?

Tags: puppet, puppetdb

As far as I understand it, storeconfigs are about storing the client data in the MySQL database.

I assume this is the data that is also stored in the .yaml-files in /var/lib/puppet/yaml/node/, that would be stored in the MySQL database.

```
[root@tst1-01 ~]# head -10 /var/lib/puppet/yaml/node/tst1-01.domain.nl.yaml
--- !ruby/object:Puppet::Node
  parameters:
    domain: domain.nl
    hardwareisa: x86_64
    clientcert: tst1-01.domain.nl
    uniqueid: "22acb249"
    selinux_current_mode: enforcing
    timezone: CEST
    role: undefined
    operatingsystem: RedHat
// A lot of more data after this
[root@tst1-01 ~]#
```

- What is the exact goal of saving the information provided by Puppet clients?
- What would you want to do with this information in the MySQL database?

Answer (score 2):

So you need stored configs for [resource collection](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_collectors.html).  In a [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/416779/smoothest-workflow-to-handle-ssh-host-verification-errors/416782#416782), I describe how to use puppet to populate `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` files on puppet clients, with the host keys of ALL the puppet nodes with SSH installed.

This works because the SSH host key is transmitted from the client to the puppet master and **stored** on the server in the database.

The storeconfigs keeps all the clients facts, so you can query the database and get lists of hosts matching certain criteria.  Some external tools use this for some functionality.