# How to add SSH known host in a bash script?

Tags: ssh, bash

I am creating a bash script to provision a new server that I can deploy a web application to. One thing I always have to do is as GitHub as a known host using `ssh git@github.com`. How can I automate this process in a bash script, and do it in an idempotent way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simple way to go would be to do something like this.

```
ssh-keyscan remote_server >>~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

If this box is brand new you might also need to create the `~/.ssh` directory before you run [ssh-keyscan](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keyscan).

Keep in mind that ssh-keyscan can take an arbitrary number of hostnames.  It will get all the keys it can.

Comment: PS - For provisioning you should be using something like puppet instead of a bash script.  For puppet this could be easily handled with the [sshkey](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#sshkey) resource.  Also see this question for a method to manage the known_hosts en-masse http://serverfault.com/a/416782/984

Comment: That sure sounded good to me, but after spending a few hours apiece on puppet and competitors, I scurried back to bash scripts and sanity. If those tools are intuitive, I apparently have no intuition. YMMV.

Comment: Use bash. I constantly run into issues across different versions of things like puppet or ansible. We always go back to bash... 3 companies running now like this and bash is always reliable for us.

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to automate accepting the new key?  If so, you could use -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no.
Doing so is a very bad idea as you're now completely wide open to man-in-the-middle attacks.

A better option would be just to manage a known_hosts file and reuse that file when you provision new servers.  Stick it on github and write a simple script to download that file before sshing into github.

The strict host key checking is a good thing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "manage known_hosts file"? I think that's what I want to do, but when I viewed the file, it's contents looked like some sort of hash/key and didn't look like something that was intended to be managed manually.

Comment: Provision a new server, manually ssh into github like you would.  Accept the host key when prompted.  Log out.  Copy ~/.ssh/known_hosts from that newly provisioned server somewhere else (github, web server, doesn't matter as long as you can get it).  Next time you provision a server, copy that file back before sshing to github.  You don't need to edit the file.

Comment: This is better than my answer (safer). A further improvement on yoonix's answer though is to parse 'ssh-keyscan github.com' and store the returned key into ~/.ssh/known_hosts that way it isn't static in a file somewhere for you to need to update.

Comment: That would work too, but I wouldn't consider it better.  You're potentially setting yourself up for a man-in-the-middle attack if you're grabbing a new host-key every time.

Comment: To clarify my last comment (too late to edit): Grabbing a new host-key each time you provision a host is functionally no different than setting StrictHostKeyChecking=no.  With either of them you're blindly trusting whatever key gets sent each time you provision.  If you think a MITM attack to be unlikely, read [these](http://www.renesys.com/2013/11/mitm-internet-hijacking/) [two](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/11/repeated-attacks-hijack-huge-chunks-of-internet-traffic-researchers-warn/) articles.  Github would be a HUGE target.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understand the question, but i think you want to ignore the known_host prompt or avoid it entirely, in which case:

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no

or other suggestions at: http://www.joedog.org/2012/07/ssh-disable-known_hosts-prompt/

Comment: I want a non-interactive way of accepting the GitHub host key (since this will happen in a bash script).

Comment: then this'll work - it won't accept the key though, it'll ignore it entirely. Yoonix's answer is better