# Puppet sshkey collection for non-puppet systems

Tags: ssh, puppet, ssh-keys

On my systems I use the [exported resources, and resource collection to manage the /etc/ssh/known_hosts ref](https://serverfault.com/a/416782/984) of my systems.  This works great for all my SSH hosts that are managed via puppet.  But I also have systems that are not managed by puppet (switches, routers, etc), and I don't have any immediate plans to start managing them.

Is there any elegant ways to get the host keys for those unmanaged systems into puppet?  Right now I just have all of them in a single big ugly class, but there must be a better way.  I have thought about somehow trying to move the keys for these hosts in to hiera, or something else, but I haven't found a solution that isn't ugly.

Does anyone have a good method/pattern I can follow here?

Comment: Oh, I just use `telnet`.

Comment: how did you go with this?

Comment: @DrewKhoury  For right now, I went with something that basically looked like what you have in your answer.  But I am not entirely happy with it, but I am not sure why.  I am still hoping someone will post an answer with something that is better.

Comment: Going to star this to see if anyone comes up with something better. if you're able to figure out why you don't like 'that' solution I might be able to give it a crack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have thought about somehow trying to move the keys for these hosts
>   in to hiera, or something else, but I haven't found a solution that
>   isn't ugly.

There are a number of ways to achieve this. I try to keep my classes generic, with all my configuration data in hiera. When I'm dealing with collections of data I try to use a hiera hash, that way I never have to change my class or define code.

1: **Use a hiera hash** to store a collection of keys.

```
hiera_key_hash:
    key-1:
        name: cisco500
        type: router
        key: xxx
    key-2:
        name: cisco100
        type: switch
        key: xxx
```

2: **Create a class** that calls a create_resource for each key (it will call the define 'key').

```
class keys {
  create_resources( "key", hiera('hiera_key_hash') )
}
```

3: **Create a define** that does the work for each key.

```
define key($name, $type, $key) {
  // code goes here
}
```

Note: At some stage you might end up storing sensitive information in your hiera. You may want to consider encrypting some of your hiera sensitive values.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... maybe in Hiera, with a `hiera_array` collecting the data, feeding that array into resources through a defined type?  Since you need hostname and key, you'll either need to put them both in a string and `split()` it in the defined type, or have the array have something more complex in it (probably a hash).

Still a headache to manage populating it and keeping it up to date; maybe a little script with a list of nodes to connect to, collect the keys from, and generate the hiera data?